# Is there a way to use in or = with a case statement in the where clause in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, csv, where-clause

I have a stored procedure that may or may not get a string list of int ids. When it doesn't get it the value is: ' '. Other wise its something like this: '500,507,908'

I'm trying to use it like this:

```
select ID as projectTeamId, Employee_ID, Supervisor_ID 
from ProjectTeam 
where Project_ID = @projectId and IsDeleted = 0 and 
        ID in (CASE @stringList WHEN '' THEN ID ELSE (SELECT * from TurnListStringIntoTable(@stringList)) END)
```

to get a result set but it errors out with this code when the string list comes in blank:

> An error has occurred while processing Report 'MassReleaseHoursReport':
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I know its an issue where id needs to = id instead of being in id. Any ideas on how I can have the case statement work with @stringList = '' then id = id else id in (SELECT * from TurnListStringIntoTable(@stringList))?

TurnListStringIntoTable returns a table from a string list which in my case is just the project Team ID

Comment: It's generally better to use AND/OR constructions instead of `case` _expressions_ in the WHERE clause.

Comment: Which database are you running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: @GMB using SQLServer

Comment: `CASE` **expression**. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend boolean logic rather than a `case` expression:

```
where 
    Project_ID = @projectId 
    and IsDeleted = 0 
    and (
        @stringList = ''
        or id in (select * from TurnListStringIntoTable(@stringList))
    )
```

Unrelated side note: if you are running SQL Server, as I suspect, and your version is 2016 or higher, you can use [built-in function `string_split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead of your customer splitter.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

All you have to do is use the parameterless flavor of `case`:

```sql
select *
from my_table t
where t.col_1 = case
         when @var in (1,2,3) then "foo"
         when @var =   4      then "bar"
         when @var in (5,6,7) then "baz"
         else                      "bat"
       end
```

One might note that the `when` expressions are not limited to looking at the same variable in any way. The only requirement is that they have to be a boolean expression. They're evaluated in order top to bottom. The first `when` clause that evaluates to `true` wins and it's `then` value is returned.

If there's no `else` and evaluation fails to find a match, the result value is `null`.

Your problem though, is that `case` expressions

- return a single value, and
- that value must be of the same type. Can have it returning a string in some cases and a table variable in another.

So... your `where` clause should look something like this:

```
where ...
  and 'true' = case
                 when @stringList = '' then 'true'
                 when ID in ( select *
                              from TurnListStringIntoTable(@stringList)
                            ) then 'true'
                 else 'false'
               end
```

You'll probably find, too, that invoking a user-defined function to convert a comma-delimited string into a table variable within the `where` clause is probably a Bad Idea™ due to the performance impact that that will have.

You'd be better off to move your `TurnListStringIntoTable` call outside of the `select` statement, thus:

```
declare @list = TurnListStringIntoTable(@stringlist)

select ...
from ProjectTeam pt
where . . .
  and @stringlist = ''
   OR exists ( select * from @list x where x.ID = pt.ID )
```